# Wordpress Coding a custom action hook

Tags: php, payment, wordpress

I am trying to develop a custom wordpress plugin to manage my membership types. To handle payments I want to have 2 custom action hooks one for `payment success` and one for `payment failure`. And if possible I want these hooks to work in all the themes.

Could not come up with a proper solution. Does anybody knows where to place the templates for membership types.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to execute your own action hook:

```
do_action( 'payment_success' )
```

Then you can 'hook onto' this hook with:

```
add_action( 'payment_success', 'your_function' )
```

Since the theme's functions.php file is loaded after all the plugins are loaded, your hook will be available in all themes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But can I handle that theme in the plugin folder too? I want all the stuff to be in the plugin only to be able to install to multiple sites.

Comment: No you need to modify the plugin so it uses your plugin, or hook it to default WordPress action hooks.