# Hooks and their hooked functions execution queue in Wordpress and Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, hook-wordpress

I am new to Wordpress/WooCommerce and PHP, although I have experience in other web platforms and languages. I have searched, but have not found the answer to my question which is...

Are hooks that are created by the "add_action" "added" to the list of actions called by that specific hook, or do they override any existing hooks of that action?

For example, if I add a `woocommerce_thankyou` hook using:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'order_created_get_skus',#);
```

**Question:** Does this override any other hooks for `woocommerce_thankyou` or does it get called in addition to any other hooks set for `woocommerce_thankyou`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Hooked functions **will never override other hooked functions that are using the same action or filter hook**.
>
> They are added to a kind of *"hook queue"* with an execution order based on priority rules:
>
> - If a priority is specified, they will be ordered in the queue first by hook priority and by declaration priority.
> - If there  is no priority specified, they take the default priority of 10 and they will be ordered in the queue by declaration.
>
> So you can have many hooked functions on the same hook, like for example in the Woocommerce template file [`content-single-product.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.4/templates/content-single-product.php)

#### Illustrated example:

In the below commented code example, you can see the execution order in the hook queue for each hooked function for the **`woocommerce_thankyou`** action hook:

```
// No defined priority (default priority is 10)
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'first_custom_function_no_priority' );
function first_custom_function_no_priority( $order_id ) {
    // ==> Triggered in third position ==> [3]
}

## Default Hook "woocommerce_order_details_table" (default priority is 10)
    // ==> Triggered in second position ==> [2]

// Defined priority is 10
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'order_created_get_skus', 10 );
function order_created_get_skus( $order_id ) {
    // ==> Triggered in Fourth position ==> [4] 
}

// Defined priority is 5
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'third_custom_function', 5 );
function third_custom_function( $order_id ) {
    // ==> Triggered in first position ==> [1]
}

// Defined priority is 20
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'fourth_custom_function', 20 );
function fourth_custom_function( $order_id ) {
    // ==> Triggered at last (sixth) ==> [6]
}

// No defined priority (default priority is 10)
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'last_custom_function_no_priority' );
function last_custom_function_no_priority( $order_id ) {
    // ==> Triggered in fifth position ==> [5]
}
```

Lower priority is executed *(or triggered)* before, higher priority is executed *(or triggered)* after. If no priority is specified, **the default priority is 10.**

> The hooked functions can only be removed with [**`remove_action()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) or [**`remove_filter()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter) with a mandatory defined priority.

To see how many hooked functions are hooked on a specific hook with all necessary details, you can use the following that will give you a raw output:

```
global $wp_filter;

// HERE below you define the targeted hook name
$hook_name = 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons';

if( isset($wp_filter[$hook_name]) ) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($wp_filter[$hook_name]);
    echo '</pre>';
} else {
    echo '<p>Hook "'.$hook_name.'" is not used yet!</p>';
}
```

---

There is 2 kind of hooks, as you have noticed may be, which are filter hooks and action hooks.

1. Action hook:

   - **Action hook execution point** *(trigger)*: with [**`do_action()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action)
   - **Attaching a function to an action hook** *(triggered)*: with [**`add_action()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action): the function is executed and can have optional arguments.
2. Filter hook:

   - **Filter hook execution point** *(trigger)*: with [**`apply_filters()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters)
   - **Attaching a function to a filter hook** *(filtering / triggered)*: with [**`add_filter()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter): a mandatory argument *(a variable)* is filtered and returned from the "hooked" function

> Hooks and their hooked functions can be located anywhere like in the function.php file of **your active child theme** *(or active theme)* and also in any **plugins** php files.

---

Related:

- [WooCommerce action hooks and overriding templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063958/woocommerce-action-hooks-and-overriding-templates/39064240#39064240)
- [How to add custom hooks to a custom plugin for Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50969720/how-to-add-custom-hooks-to-a-custom-plugin-for-woocommerce)
- [WordPress: Difference Between Filter and Action Hooks?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/difference-between-filter-and-action-hooks)