# When exactly woocommerce/wordpress hooks are called?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, hook-wordpress

I know there are hundreds of action hooks available in Wordpress and in Woocommerce plugin, but what is most confusing to me is: when exactly they are invoked?

For some of the hooks there are some information available in the internet, but for many of them I do not see any information available.

For example when I was checking the code of some custom plugin, I see following hooks :

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue_scripts' ) );
add_action( 'woocommerce_settings_api_form_fields_cod', array( $this, 'extend_cod' ) );
add_action( 'woocommerce_settings_api_sanitized_fields_cod', array( $this, 'clean_up_settings' ) );
add_action( 'woocommerce_delete_shipping_zone', array( $this, 'clean_up_gateway' ) );
```

My questions are where I can get the list of all the hooks for Woocommerce/Wordpress ?
In the above example whether hooks starting with 'woocommerce_' are part of standard hooks or they are custom hooks specific to plugin ?
Is it possible to create custom hooks ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [2 kinds of hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50969720/how-to-add-custom-hooks-to-a-custom-plugin-for-woocommerce/50987153#50987153): Action hooks and filter hooks.

Hooks are added/created via [`do_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/) or [`apply_filters()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/) functions.

Hooks are triggered when the code where that [`do_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/) or [`apply_filters()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/) are located run.

You can attach a callback function to an existing hook using [`add_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) or [`add_filter()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/).

- Wordpress hooks: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/
- Woocommerce hooks: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html
- All plugins and themes have their own hooks.
- So YES you can create your own custom hooks.

Note: There is also a lot of undocumented hooks like most of various composite hooks.

---

Related:

- [WooCommerce action hooks and overriding templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063958/woocommerce-action-hooks-and-overriding-templates/39064240#39064240)
- [How to add custom hooks to a custom plugin for Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50969720/how-to-add-custom-hooks-to-a-custom-plugin-for-woocommerce/50987153#50987153)
- [Hooks and their hooked functions execution queue in Wordpress and Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52765303/hooks-and-their-hooked-functions-execution-queue-in-wordpress-and-woocommerce/52767950#52767950)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it like "add_action" is for registering the hook and "do_action" for executing the function associated with the hook ? In the example above when the hook 'woocommerce_settings_api_form_fields_cod' would be invoked ?

Comment: @user2679476 `do_action()` and `apply_filters()` native WordPress functions invokes all functions attached to a hook… `add_action()` and `apply_filters()` attach a/some function(s) to a hook… So for example, when `woocommerce_settings_api_form_fields_cod` hook is triggered, all functions attached to that hook will run.